# How to create a constructor that takes multiple arguments?

Tags: python, function, variadic-functions

I have a certain class and i'm having difficulty setting up the`__init__` constructor. I need it to take in zero or more strings as arguments, each giving a city name and state abbreviation, and indicating a destination along a tour of US cities.

For example:

```
Tour("New York, NY", "Lansing, MI", "Los Angeles, CA")
```

represents a tour that starts in New York city, proceeds to Lansing, and ends in Los Angeles.

Any ideas how to go about doing this using python 3.3?

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
class Tour:
    def __init__(self, *cities):
        # cities is a tuple of arguments, do what you want with it
```

When you call

```
Tour("New York, NY", "Lansing, MI", "Los Angeles, CA")
```

`cities` in `__init__` will be set to `("New York, NY", "Lansing, MI", "Los Angeles, CA")`.

Comment: This will do, you then access `cities` like any tuple: `cities[0]`... etc.

Comment: how can i create cities into a tuple of arguments though?

Answer (score 1):

> This may help...

**Example**

```
class Bar:
   def __init__ (self, arg1=None, arg2=None, ... argN=None):

class NEW (Bar):    
    def __init__ (self, my_new_arg=None, ??? )
       self.new_arg = my_new_arg
       Bar.__init__(self, ??? )
```